# Outside of combat, does a Totem Warrior Barbarian with Eagle Totemic Attunement still fall from flight?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, flight, falling

Say a 14th-level Totem Barbarian chose the Eagle totem for the level 14 Totemic Attunement feature, and had the Persistent Rage barbarian feature.

Would they fall after flying 80 feet, assuming they have a base speed of 40 feet from the Fast Movement feature, and take the Dash action? Or would they be able to fly continuously for 1 minute?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Does a Barbarian need to be in combat to rage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103425/does-a-barbarian-need-to-be-in-combat-to-rage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You fall if you end your turn in the air and nothing else is holding you aloft

If something is defined in terms of rounds, the DM switches to round based time scale when it becomes relevant. They might not ask everyone to roll initiative, but instead do it in their head.

The intent here clearly is that a barbarian can not stay in the air for longer than 6 seconds at a time, and that should hold true whether you are inside initiative order or outside.